# Endpoint.publish doesn't work after proguard obfuscation

Tags: java, java-8, proguard

I want to offuscated my code.
My application start a web service.

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
@Override
protected void run() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting Server");
    basicHttpBinding_ITestServiceImpl = new BasicHttpBinding_ITestServiceImpl();
    logger.debug("BasicHttpBinding_ITestServiceImpl is created");
    ep = Endpoint.create(basicHttpBinding_ITestServiceImpl);
    logger.debug("Endpoint created");
    ep.publish(this.address);

    logger.info("Server ready...");
}
```

The code works correctly before obfuscation.
But when I try to obfuscate my code, the execution is block on **ep.publish(this.address);**

For information I use **proguard** for obfuscated my code.

If someone have any idea?
I have no issue during compilation and obfuscation.
My class is not obffuscated (but other class was).

Comment: Could you share your config? Also, is the obfuscated class you referred to in your question related to your problematic class?

Comment: https://framabin.org/?2388dc5ff0f2628e#VED/TiXlNdjVjG/SP5Wt4jSVC7bJ3G9jX3KPZdQxTfs=

Comment: no my class is not obfuscated, but other class yes. (not link between obfuscated classe and this one no obfuscated)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't kept `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint`. You need to keep all the dependencies you are using, and all the codes you haven't written yourself. Otherwise, obfuscating them will cause problems. Remember to keep all jars you are using, and add the following line to your config:

```
-keep class javax.xml.**;
```